# How to store mathematical symbols and formulas in column sqlalchemy Postgres as DB

Tags: python, postgresql, flutter, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have two questions:

1. What I want to do is to be able to store a mathematical question with special symbols, formulas that are part of the text. What column should I define in SQLAlchemy so that I can get back the equation without any issue.
2. Second part involves in data entry, I want to upload questions in bulk, now the special symbols cannot be defined/written as text in excel, I was able to do it in MSWord. Is there any specific rules that I can define so I can read the equation in that rule and transform it into mathematical equation. For Ex. similar to latex, if we type [\sqrt{x^2+1}], we see the math format in pdf. That way I can provide a input text where they can write equations in that format and it automatically converts it into math formulae and display it as such.

Now is there any intelligent way to achieve this? I'm using Fastapi with SQLAlchemy and for database, I'm using Postgres. If you could point me to relevant resources, that would be of great help.

Comment: As long as your symbols are proper utf-8 symbols they should work out of the box with just the Text column types for most database engines (if you'd been using MySQL and not postgres, you'd need to make sure that utf8mb4 was the selected charset). For rendering and special symbols, [something like MathJax might be what you're looking for](https://www.mathjax.org/)?

Comment: I see, so as long as characters are utf-8, that solves with storing in db, and for rendering I can use the JS, Is there any flutter plugin available that you know of which would do just the same? Thank you. I really appreciate it.